# Vulkan is giving me errors for no reason

Tags: rust, vulkan

I am trying to program a triangle in Rust based on the C++ tutorial at vulkan-tutorial.com. I can see my triangle, but my program stops responding after finishing the `drawFrame` function 3 times. The `drawFrame` function:

```rust
unsafe {
    vkWaitForFences(
        self.vulkan.logical_device,
        1,
        &self.vulkan.in_flight_fences[self.vulkan.current_frame as usize],
        VK_TRUE,
        18446744073709551615, // uint_max
    );
}

let mut image_index = 0;
let wait_stages = VkPipelineStageFlagBits_VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
unsafe {
    let result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(
        self.vulkan.logical_device,
        self.vulkan.swapchain,
        u64::MAX,
        self.vulkan.image_available_semaphore[self.vulkan.current_frame as usize],
        null_mut(),
        &mut image_index,
    );
    if result != VkResult_VK_SUCCESS {
        panic!("Couldn't aquire next image. Error code: {}", result);
    }
}

if self.vulkan.images_in_flight[image_index as usize] != null_mut() {
    unsafe {
        vkWaitForFences(
            self.vulkan.logical_device,
            1,
            &self.vulkan.images_in_flight[image_index as usize],
            VK_TRUE,
            18446744073709551615, // uint_max
        );
    }
}

let wait_semaphores =
    [self.vulkan.image_available_semaphore[self.vulkan.current_frame as usize]];
let signal_semaphores =
    [self.vulkan.render_finished_semaphore[self.vulkan.current_frame as usize]];

self.vulkan.images_in_flight[image_index as usize] =
    self.vulkan.in_flight_fences[self.vulkan.current_frame as usize];

let mut submit_info: VkSubmitInfo = unsafe { core::mem::zeroed() };
submit_info.sType = VkStructureType_VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
submit_info.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
submit_info.pWaitSemaphores = wait_semaphores.as_ptr();
submit_info.pWaitDstStageMask = &wait_stages;
submit_info.commandBufferCount = 1;
submit_info.pCommandBuffers = &self.vulkan.command_buffers[image_index as usize];
submit_info.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
submit_info.pSignalSemaphores = signal_semaphores.as_ptr();

unsafe {
    vkResetFences(
        self.vulkan.logical_device,
        1,
        &self.vulkan.in_flight_fences[self.vulkan.current_frame as usize],
    );
}

let result = unsafe {
    vkQueueSubmit(
        self.vulkan.graphics_queue,
        1,
        &submit_info,
        self.vulkan.in_flight_fences[self.vulkan.current_frame as usize],
    )
};
if result != VkResult_VK_SUCCESS {
    panic!(
        "failed to submit draw command buffer. Error code: {}",
        result
    );
}

let mut present_info: VkPresentInfoKHR = unsafe { core::mem::zeroed() };
present_info.sType = VkStructureType_VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
present_info.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
present_info.pWaitSemaphores = self.vulkan.render_finished_semaphore.as_ptr();
present_info.swapchainCount = 1;
present_info.pSwapchains = &self.vulkan.swapchain;
present_info.pImageIndices = &image_index;
present_info.pResults = null_mut();
unsafe {
    vkQueuePresentKHR(self.vulkan.present_queue, &present_info);
}

self.vulkan.current_frame = (self.vulkan.current_frame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
```

It gives me errors which mean nothing to me:

```
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-QueueForwardProgress and VUID-vkQueuePresentKHR-pWaitSemaphores-03268.
```

I don't wish to use vulkano or other crates, I just want to know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you are waiting on the wrong semaphore.

You signal `self.vulkan.render_finished_semaphore[self.vulkan.current_frame]`, but then on present wait on `self.vulkan.render_finished_semaphore[0]`.